# Jupyter notebook output redirection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, stdout

I'd like to redirect the output of each cell of my notebook. Here is what I tried

```
class Logger():
    def __init__(self, stdout):
        self.stdout = stdout

    def write(self, msg):
        self.stdout.write('augmented:' + msg)

    def flush(self):
        self.stdout.flush()
```

and in a cell, I change the `stdout` on the fly

```
sys.stdout = Logger(sys.stdout)
```

However, the output string of the next executed cells has not the "augmented" string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `contextlib`.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys
@contextmanager
def stdout_redirector():
    class MyStream:
        def write(self, msg):
            prefix = 'augmented:' if msg.strip() else ''
            old_stdout.write( prefix + msg)
        def flush(self):
            old_stdout.flush()
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = MyStream()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

[image: output]

It is better to use `with` statement to manage the redirection. If that's not possible in your case, calling the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods of the redirector object also works. You can also put those redirector codes in the `pre_run_cell` and `post_run_cell` [hook function](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html#pre-run-cell) in IPython.

Comment: The events in IPython were exactly what I was looking for ! I was not aware of there existence.